# What does mean "inertial forces" in the Reynolds number definition?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've always seen Reynolds number defined as the ratio between inertial and viscous forces, but I understand inertial forces as the "forces" you feel when you are in a non-inertial reference, hence I can't understand its meaning in the Reynolds number definition.

Thank you.

Comment: Fluid mechanics definition of inertia force is different: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/reynolds-number-and-inertial-force

Answer (score 3):

You can understand it as following. 
Consider Fluid  in motion( flowing in a pipe or over a flat plate etc). The forward motion of the fluid is opposed by the viscous forces. Reynolds number gives us the idea i.e of the ratio of Force that tries to push to the fluid forward to that force which tries to pull it backward.
The "force which tries to push it forward" is what you are referring to the inertial force 
and "the force trying to pull it backward is the viscous force"
If viscous force is dominating then the flow will tend to be laminar flow and if inertial flow is dominating then the flow will tend to be turbulent