# Inertial stresses in Reynolds number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, inertia

What is meant by the inertial stress in the definition of Reynolds number? 
Reynolds number = Inertial stress/ viscous stress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is that the "inertial stress" as referenced in the Reynolds number definition is equivalent to a dynamic pressure $\rho v^2$, where $\rho$ and $v$ are some characteristic density and speed of the flow respectively.

Note that this isn't a unique way of defining the Reynolds number; you can do it by taking the ratio of "inertial forces" to viscous forces as in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/reynolds-number-and-inertial-force?rq=1) answer. The key concept is that the Reynolds number compares the inertial effects of a flow to the viscous effects of a flow, and that can be done through any number of equivalent ratios (inertial to viscous length scales, etc.)

Comment: Shouldn't the dynamic pressure have a 2 in the denominat0r?

Comment: For the dynamic pressure referenced in the Bernoulli equation, it would indeed carry a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$; however, the typical definition of characteristic dynamic pressure used for the definition of a Reynolds number doesn't. This is because the particular form of Reynolds number the OP describes is $Re = \frac{\rho v^2}{\mu \frac{v}{L}}$, which straightforwardly simplifies to its common form; but the addition of constant flow-independent factors is common and perfectly fine in defining Reynolds numbers as long as you do the proper book-keeping for it.

Comment: What is dynamic pressure? Is it different than pressure? That is force/area?? And also with the characterstic density?

Comment: This definition of dynamic pressure is proportional to a characteristic kinetic energy density of the fluid, which is naturally a function of a characteristic mass density and speed. It’s not the same thing as “normal” or mechanical pressure (which is the mean isotropic stress at a point), but note that it has the same units as pressure or force per area, so it’s the same -type- of object.

Comment: Hello sir , sorry for being such a naive in physics, Sir can you please tell me what is this "characterstic" in the the above answers when you used characterstic density and characteristics kinetic energy density , pardon me sir again for being such a naive

Comment: Characteristic -insert property here- refers to a value of -insert property here- that you expect to be the value of -insert property here- mostly everywhere in the flow. For example, the characteristic speed of a pipe flow is usually defined as the mean velocity of the liquid in the pipe, and the characteristic speed of a flow induced by a moving solid body is the speed of the immersed solid body.